# Subscript tuple-unpacking notation in comprehensions

Tags: python, syntax

So when I have objects

```
[*range(4)]
[*zip([1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6])]
```

and use tuple-unpacking, is there a way to subscript the tuple-unpacking notation which could look like this:

```
[*range(4)[2]]
[*[2]zip([1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6])]
```

Without using subscript on the whole comprehension?

```
[[*range(4)][2]]
[[*zip([1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6])][2]]
```

Comment: The short answer is no. The longer answer is: How would you define what `[*range(4)[2]]` is supposed to mean? You obviously can't splat `range(4)[2]`, because that's the number `2`, not any kind of iterable. And if you changed the precedence so it meant `[(*range(4))[2]]`… I can _maybe_ see how that could give you `[[2]]`, but not `[2]`.

Comment: Meanwhile, why are you even trying to use splatting here? Why not just `[range(4)[2]]`, or `[list(zip([1,2,3], [4,5,6]))[2]]`, which already do what you seem to want? For that matter, why are you building single-element lists instead of just building the elements themselves?

Comment: One last thing: there's no comprehension in any of your examples. These are just normal list displays. A comprehension is when you put a `for` clause (or rather 1 or more `for` clauses and 0 or more `if` clauses) inside the brackets to build a list by looping over another iterable.

Comment: @abarnert thanks for the clarification. Both of the snippets were merly ment as examples for the underlying principle.

Comment: If you’re interested, you should read the two accepted PEPs that expanded on unpacking between Python 2.3 and today, and the linked threads on the python-ideas and -dev lists. And then, if you can come up with well-defined syntax and semantics (and useful real-life examples) for a further extension that would make the language even better, you can even suggest it yourself on -ideas. The worst-case scenario is that Guido or another core dev tells you why it doesn’t fit well with Python (which, for me, has been a very useful learning experience a couple times…).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you cannot slice an unpacking operation.

There are various possible workarounds though:

- If the iterable you're unpacking can be sliced, just slice it directly. For example, to get the 3rd element of a `range`:

  ```
  >>> [*range(4)[2:3]]
  [2]
  ```

  So why are we using `[2:3]` here? It's simple: `range(4)[2]` would return a single integer, and integers can't be unpacked:

  ```
  >>> [*range(4)[2]]
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
  ```

  But `range(4)[2:3]` returns a single-element list, so the unpacking succeeds.
- If the iterable can't be sliced, slice it anyway by using [`itertools.islice`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice):

  ```
  >>> [*itertools.islice(zip([1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]), 2, 3)]
  [(3, 6)]
  ```
- If you only want a single element of a slice-able iterable, just don't unpack the iterable at all:

  ```
  >>> [range(4)[2]]
  [2]
  ```

Comment: Using an unpacking at all just to select one element seems pointless, though.